# Save GM directions as KML - with timestamps?

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-earth, timestamp

In Google Maps I use Get Directions and after saving the result as a 'map' and opening it in My Places I am able to save it as a KML. All fine up to a point, allowing me to display the route in Google Earth.

But I'd also like to **animate** it with GE's Time Slider. Given that the GM directions assumes speeds and provides an estimated journey time, is it possible to get GM to save the KML with timestamps please?

Otherwise I must edit the 'raw' KML elsewhere and add arbitrary times myself, a relatively tedious task.

-- 
Terry, East Grinstead, UK